# Question about creating an excel file in Python. Question about syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Considering I have this code. (Creating a new excel file)

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()                                    
sheet = wb['Sheet']
sheet.title = 'Hobbies'
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

I'm trying to figure out this lines:

```
sheet = wb['Sheet']
sheet.title = 'Hobbies'
```

What do they mean?

```
sheet = wb['Sheet']
```

`wb` is an instance of Workbook() class.

Is `sheet` an instance too? Because in the command below we then use it
to call title method. What the meaning of the square brackets with the Sheet quotation marks?

I also saw something similar in `tkinter` module to change the font parameter,
after creating an instance to change the text of the instance attribute. like that, it's the same like my first example?

```
lable1 = tkinter.Label(frame1, font=("ariel",11))
lable1 .grid(row=0, column=0, padx=8)

lable1['text'] = "new label"
```

Can someone explain it to me more deeply ? I'm confused with it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's comment your code line by line:

```py
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
```

In this line you create an object of type Workbook, which will be saved later as an xlsx on disk. By default an xlsx file has only one sheet called 'Sheet'. You can add several other sheets if you need, but that's another story.

```py
sheet = wb['Sheet']
```

The `sheet` variable will refer that single sheet of your object. The 'sheet' variable is of type `Worksheet` and has an attribute called `title` with the value 'Sheet'. As an exercise, run the following code to see the titles of all the sheets of a Workbook:

```py
for s in wb:
    print(s.title)
```

Let's go further with your code:

```py
sheet.title = 'Hobbies'
```

In this line you just change the title of that single sheet of the file. After you save the file just open it and you will notice that it contains a single sheet called 'Hobbies'. If you haven't ran the above line, that single sheet of the file would have been called 'Sheet' which is the default name.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation.
I already understand the functionality. I ran the code before...
But I'm not sure it's answer my question...I'm not understand the meaning of the syntax by writing wb['Sheet']
if 'Sheet' is a variable.. why to write it in a list as a string? How the instance wb refer to ['Sheet']?

so now sheet is a new instance ? a copy of wb that refer to the specific attribute 'Sheet'? 
I'm not get it ...

Comment: The Workbook is a mapping data type, where its elements are organised in key:value pairs, similar to the dictionaries. So, `wb['Sheet']` is a reference to the Worksheet object stored in wb which has the key 'Sheet'. ```sheet = wb['Sheet']``` means that the sheet variable will get a reference to the element wb['Sheet']. It doesn't mean that sheet is a new instance of Worksheet but just refers to an existing Worksheet. I suggest you read about python dictionaries as a start and things will become more clear.

Comment: Yes thanks for the explanation it's getting more clear now...I didn't know it's a form of dictionary, I will read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `wb['Sheet']` you're looking up a `worksheet` inside of the `workbook` with the `title` of `'Sheet'`.

We can verify it here:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

print(f'Before: {wb.sheetnames}')  # Output: Before: ['Sheet']
sheet = wb['Sheet']
sheet.title = 'Hobbies'
print(f'After: {wb.sheetnames}')  # Output: After: ['Hobbies']

print(f'Type of sheet: {type(sheet)}') # Output: Type of sheet: <class 'openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet'>
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

As you can see above, the variable `sheet` is an instance of the `worksheet` class. So basically what is happening is that you're changing the `title` of the default `worksheet` that is created inside of a `workbook`.

Comment: How does sheet become an instance of worksheet class ? By writing sheet = wb['Sheet']

Comment: @eliran.n It is automatically created when you either 1. Create a completely new Workbook. Or 2. When read-in an already created Workbook. You can read more about in [here in the documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#module-openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet). However, do note what is written on that page: `Do not create worksheets yourself, use openpyxl.workbook.Workbook.create_sheet() instead`.